# spacemacs installation: Git-gutter and helm

Tags: spacemacs

I'm trying install spacemacs in Elementary OS(Linux) and recive the following error:

`Error (use-package): git-gutter+ :init: Cannot open load file: git-gutter+
Error (use-package): helm pre-:config hook: Symbol's function definition is void: helm-flx-mode
Error (use-package): helm pre-:config hook: Symbol's function definition is void: helm-flx-mode`

[image]

I already searched for this error, but I can't resolve it. What I suppose to do?

**Update**
I resolved this by upgrading emacs to 24.5 and installing the latest git version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the exact same error when I was emacs-24.3.1. I fixed it by upgrading to the latest one.

Comment: By upgrade, you mean compile emacs? I tried it(emacs-25) and didn't work...it don't read my .emacs.d folder